# How to change the labelText position a little down

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]

How to position the label inside the border rather than on the border

Answer (score 1):

height value increase the label will more inside the border.
if height value negative the label will out side the border

```
TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                labelText: 'Enter a search term',
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  height: 3
                )
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use label style and add a height property. If you add height less than 1 the label would be lowered

```
labelStyle: TextStyle(
          height:0.7,
        )
```

Comment: This Works labelText moved down  ,but this is hidding the portion of border that was earlier occupied by the label